# How to toggle the way my elements looked before they were clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and jquery for an HTML page. I want to toggle the way my elements looked before and after the button is clicked. I have the code jquery code below and the full code for the module I want in the codepen

HTML code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LOGIN</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-part col-lg-6">
      <div class="row row-loginpart">
        <div class="dropdown col-lg-12 reg-user">
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle reg-user-btn"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
          >
            Regular User Login
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu reg-user">
            <form class="px-4 py-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  type="email"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1"
                  placeholder="email@example.com"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  type="password"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1"
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="form-check-input"
                  id="dropdownCheck"
                />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
                  Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="alink" href="#">Sign up</a>
            <a class="alink" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Default dropup button -->
        <div class="btn-group dropup col-lg-12 vendor-user">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle vendor-user"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
          >
            Vendor Login
          </button>

          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <form class="px-4 py-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  type="email"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1"
                  placeholder="email@example.com"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  type="password"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1"
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="form-check-input"
                  id="dropdownCheck"
                />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
                  Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="alink" href="#">Sign up</a>
            <a class="alink" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jquer script cdn -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap scripts start -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- bootstrap scripts end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.row-loginpart {
  margin-top: 8rem;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 95%;
}

.show {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.dropup-button.col-lg-12 {
  top: 17rem;
}

.alink {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

jquery code

```
var timesClicked = 0;
$(".reg-user-btn").on("click", function () {
  timesClicked++;
  console.log("clicked" + timesClicked);
  if (timesClicked % 2 === 0)
    if (
      $(".row").hasClass("row-loginpart") &&
      $(".vendor-user").hasClass("dropup-button")
    ) {
      $(".row").addClass("row-loginpart");
      $(".vendor-user").removeClass("dropup-button");
    }
  if (timesClicked % 2 === 1)
    if (
      $(".row").not("row-loginpart") &&
      $(".vendor-user").not("dropup-button")
    ) {
      $(".row").removeClass("row-loginpart");
      $(".vendor-user").addClass("dropup-button");
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/tk1017/pen/xxZwmgY

I don't know why my elements don't come back to the positions as they were before after they button is clicked again. I also tried logging whether my eventhandler gets called for every click and it does. Why it doesn't work?

P.S:
The HTML code contains a lot of scripts and cdns, please consider the code inside the body.

Comment: Please add _relevant_ code to your question instead of pointing to an external site

Comment: That's probably the `.dropup-button` has never successfully removed. You may add a console log to check if that `if` statement has been accessed successfully.

Comment: @LuudJacobs I have edited as you asked, please help me with the issue.

Comment: @yinsweet first the ```.row-loginpart``` is removed and ```.dropup-button``` is added, for the first click. Then on the next click the reverse should be done, but it isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am the one who posted the question. I should have checked my logic. The problem was with the outer if condition when remainder equals 0.

```
      $(".row").hasClass("row-loginpart") &&
      $(".vendor-user").hasClass("dropup-button")
    )
```

For the first click, the class `.row-loginpart` is removed and the class `.dropup-button` is added. When the second click happens there is no class named `.row-loginpart` so the above statement evaluates to false. So the code below that doesn't execute.

Thanks for the effort if any body is still going through this issue or have looked at this issue.

So the below replacement solves the issue, for the inner if where we check for an even click

```
      $(".row").not("row-loginpart") &&
      $(".vendor-user").hasClass("dropup-button")
    )
```